# The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues. (line 13,)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting a "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues. (line 13)"error in my Google Apps Script when I try to write to a sheet.
I want to get followers of Instagram profiles using Instagram profile url. The Url's are in column J and followers in column in K.

```js
function scrapeInstaFollowers() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
for(var i=2; i<ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
 
 var url1 = "http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=&url="
 var url2 = ss.getRange("J"+[i]).getValue();
 var finalUrl = url1+url2;
 var getContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl).getContentText();
 var getContent = getContent.trim();
 var followerRegex = /meta property="og:description".*Followers/gi
 var getFollowers = getContent.match(followerRegex)
 var followers = getFollowers[0].replace('meta property="og:description" content="',"")
 ss.getRange("K"+i).setValues([followers]); 
 
}
 
}
```

Comment: Can you log `followers` before you try to put them in column K and share it here please? Of course, sanitise the information, only the data structure is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're just setting the value of one cell so setValues() is not the correct choice:

Change this:

```
ss.getRange("K"+i).setValues([followers]);
```

To this:

```
ss.getRange("K"+i).setValue(followers);
```